# Does javascript implementation of claimedBarcodeScanner.SetActiveSymbologiesAsync work?

Tags: javascript, win-universal-app, barcode-scanner, windows-10-universal

We are using the `Windows.Devices.PointOfService` API directly in javascript to operate the barcode scanner on two different Windows 10 mobile devices.

On both devices, we can successfully enable, disable and soft start and stop the scan engine. However, it appears that setActiveSymbologiesAsync does not do anything through javascript. It does work in the **.NET/C# API**.

Each device will only scan what appears to be a default set of symbologies.

Does anybody have experience with it ?

I am calling it like this:

```
var syms = [ Windows.Devices.PointOfService.BarcodeSymbologies.code128 ];
claimedScanner.setActiveSymbologiesAsync(syms);
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that JavaScript arrays are not agile, and methods like `setActiveSymbologiesAsync` handle them incorrectly. (There are other methods in the `PointOfService` namespace with the same problem. Basically, look for methods that are async and which accept an array of strings.)

Thanks for reporting the bug. The team tells me that the fix is on track to be fixed in the Anniversary Update. Until then, you can try this workaround:

```
function createAgileStringArray() {
    var contact = new Windows.ApplicationModel.Contacts.Contact();
    return contact.dataSuppliers;
}

var syms = createAgileStringArray();
syms.push(Windows.Devices.PointOfService.BarcodeSymbologies.code128);
claimedScanner.setActiveSymbologiesAsync(syms);
```

Basically, we create a dummy contact, not because we actually care about the contact, but only so we can repurpose the agile string array that comes with it: `dataSuppliers`.

I don't have a barcode scanner to be able to test the workaround myself. Let me know if it works.

Comment: I did try it and I get a Method not found error when calling setActiveSymbologiesAsync. I don't think that the different array type works with that method call.  Thank you for the idea, however.

Comment: @JRB I cant update my devices to Aniversary. And using Windows.ApplicationModel.Contacts.Contact.dataSuppliers does not work.

Any ideas?